# Can't run phpunit on phpstorm due to Undefined variable: argv in

Tags: php

I have everything configured but when I run the tests it fails with this error log:

```
/usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap /home/lchost/EOSS2/tests/bootstrap.php --no-configuration /home/lchost/EOSS2/tests
Testing started at 9:02 PM ...
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: argv in /tmp/ide-phpunit.php(191) : eval()'d code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
PHP   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:250
PHP   3. eval() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:191
This version of PHPUnit is supported on PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0, and PHP 7.1.
You are using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (/usr/bin/php5).
```

What should I do? I was trying to update php5.5.9 to php5.6 but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

For the Notice message, from PHP for argv variable.
enable **register_argc_argv** in you php.ini file.

And for testing, upgrade your php.
You are getting Notice that will not affect your execution of the test. So thats not a problem for the PHPUnit.